# function should not change current view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a form that submits to a function and returns a particular view when certain values are submitted.
However I require it to return nothing when no values are matched, or if values are empty. At the moment, when this happens I am redirected to a blank page.
I require a function to return "something", so the view is not changed.
Returning 'nothing' or 'emptyresult', still yields a blank page.

regards,
Andrew.

Comment: Please provide more details - as it stands, this question is difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a new view to the browser. If you want to display the same view again as before, then you should redirect to the action which rendered the previous view (`RedirectToAction`).